# Is NopCommerce only usable with Javascript enabled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

In the demo shop (http://demo.nopcommerce.com/) I cant use some essential buttons like "Add To Cart" or  "Submit" (Newsletter) if I dont have Javascript enabled.

Is this just a frontend design issue, or are parts of the shop not implemented for use without javascript enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Add To Cart" or "Submit" (Newsletter)  will not work if JavaScript is disabled. 
nopCommerce use **AJAX**.

**Add to cart**

```
<input type="button" 
onclick="AjaxCart.addproducttocart('/addproducttocart/13');return false;" 
class="button-2 product-box-add-to-cart-button" value="Add to cart">
```